# How to assign a value to a string outside the declaration in C ? Bus error/segfault

Tags: c, string, macos, unix, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to recode the equivalent of an `strstr()` function, after a few try I got it right, here the code:

(I know there are simpler way to do it which I did, but this time I wanted to try by using a 3rd string to stock the occurrence)

```
 char *my_strstr(char *s1, char *s2)
 {
   int i, j;
   char *tmp;
   i = (j = 0);
   if (s1 != '\0' && s2 != '\0')
     {
       while (s1[i] != '\0' && s2[j] != '\0')
         {
           if (s1[i] == s2[j])
             {
               tmp[j] = s1[i];
               j++;
             }
           i++;
         }
         printf("tmp = %s\n", tmp);
     }
   return (tmp);
 }


 int main()
 {
   char a[] = "test Point123";
   char b[] = "Point123";
   char *ret;

   ret = my_strstr(a, b);
   printf("ret = %s\n",ret);

   return (0);
 }
```

I get the output I wanted:

```
tmp = Point123
ret = Point123
```

But then just to be sure I tried with a longer string, and that's where the problems started. 
Here the string I tried,

```
char a[] = "test Point123456789";
char b[] = "Point123456789";
```

and the output I got with it:

```
tmp = Point123456?"1
ret = Point123456?"1
Abort trap: 6
```

With longer string I get sometimes segfault, sometimes bus Error 10.
On some other post I figured that the Bus error 10 sometimes replace a segfault on mac OS (on which I'm coding for the 1st time, I'm used to code on linux), I didnt find anything about the trap tho.

Anyway I figured its more a code problem that my compiler and I'd like to know why my code function on smaller string but not bigger ones, and I read that it could be how I affected value to the strings I'm using but I dont understand where I'm making an error.

So if anyone could give me a clue on what I'm doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate it :)

**EDIT**

I followed the advices in the comments, here is the function after I fixed it, it runs fine now thx.

(Again, I know I dont need a tmp and there are many other simpler and faster way to do it - it was meant as training (which apparently I needed ^^))

```
char *my_strstr(char *s1, char *s2)
{
  int i, j;
  char *tmp;
  i = (j = 0);
  tmp = malloc(sizeof(strlen(s2)));
  if (s1 != '\0' && s2 != '\0')
    {
      while (s1[i] != '\0' && s2[j] != '\0')
        {
          if (s1[i] == s2[j])
            {
              tmp[j] = s1[i];
              j++;
            }
          else
            j = 0;
          i++;
        }
    }
  return (tmp);
}
```

Comment: Can you please remove the line numbers? It's hard to run your code through a compiler if each line begins with a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `tmp` is an automatic local variable to your function `my_strstr()`. It is not initialized explicitly, so it contains indeterministic value.

Later in the code, you're directly writing

```
 tmp[j] = s1[i];
```

Using (dereferencing) `tmp` uninitialized means you're trying to access invalid memory location (*remember the "indeterministic value"?*), which may not be accessible from your application. It  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: You need to allocate memory to `tmp` before you access (dereference) it.

---

EDIT:

However, as per the below [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831723/how-to-assign-a-value-to-a-string-outside-the-declaration-in-c-bus-error-segfa/31831825?noredirect=1#comment51587209_31831825) from [Mr. Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow), your logic for `my_strstr()` is also buggy. Once you're incrementing the `j` (*index for the search string*) and finding a mismatch in between, you're not re-setting it to `0`. Maybe you want to have another look at it and correct  the same.

Comment: Ah yeah I malloc it and that works, thx for the quick answer I should've know, I was confused by the fact that it worked the 1st time. I didnt know  the ineterministic value your talking about existed at all.

Comment: @Zoubro You're welcome. and regarding the indeterministic value, every automatic local variable value is indeterministic, unless initialized explicitly. :-)

Comment: Ok thats good to know, and does that value depend on the type of the variable, is it always the same or maybe random?

Comment: @Zoubro always nondeterministic unless initialized, regardless of the type.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh No, he need not to allocate memory to tmp. He simply should not use tmp. But in any case his function is wrong.

Comment: @Zoubro Even if you will use malloc for temp nevertheless your function is wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry sir, why? If I allocate memory to `tmp`, returning `tmp` should be valid, no? `return &tmp;` is invalid, agree.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh He is changing j within the loop and does not reinitialize it. His function does not make sense.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh That is his function has nothing common with strstr. It always returns a non-zero pointer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you sir, I ignored (should not have, sorry) that part of logical aspect. Please don't remove your comment, I'll refer to it in my answer. Please wait for the edit.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know I shouldn't use tmp I've also done it in recursive and it works fine and it take 4/5 lines, as I said I did it this way for the sake of training. I see you point tho

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh I read your edit, why should I rest 'j' to 0? All I want is the first occurence between the two strings if they stop matching I return the occurence it found and thats it, or is there something I'm not seeing yet?

Comment: @Zoubro how about a source like "helloworld" and a search string of "held"?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Oh yeah I see that now, I runned it and expected "hel" as output but I got "held" instead, I working on fixing it

Comment: Tho I dont get why it does that since my condition is if (s1 =  s2) and, well they are not at some point so in my mind it should stop incrementing by itself and return what I want

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh I fixed it  with what you said, I just added an 'else  j=0;' after my condition in the loop, tho I still dont get why it continued to increment 'j' since it was not suppose to enter the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You did not allocate memory for `tmp` so with `tmp[j]` you're writing to some random memory location which was not assigned to you.  And this location may then be overwritten again by the things you do.

The longer the strings the more memory locations you're messing up.

You're just lucky that you got some results with shorter strings.